# Referring a long phrase

Tags: single-word-requests

**Example:** In Arabic, "Bismillahir Rahmanir Raheem" [you may see different transliterations, or all written as one word] means "All the praises and thanks be to Allah, the Lord of the worlds." In writing and speech it is typically referred as "bismillah". [You may come across "basmala" and perhaps other variations also.] Bismallah is not the name of "Bismillahir Rahmanir Raheem", nor its acronym.

Is there a word in English for such referencing?

Answer (score 1):

#### Revised answer after comments from OP

According to [the Wikipedia page on *Basmala*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basmala), **Bismillah** is an **incipit**. [According to ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/incipit), the definition of *incipit* is:

> "The opening of a manuscript, early printed book, or chanted liturgical text."[3](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/incipit)

#### First answer

**Colloquialism**. According to [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/colloquialism):

> "A word or phrase that is not formal or literary and is used in ordinary or familiar conversation."[1](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/colloquialism)

#### Attribution

[1](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/colloquialism) "Colloquialism | Definition of Colloquialism in English by Oxford Dictionaries." Oxford Dictionaries | English. Accessed March 22, 2018. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/colloquialism.

[3](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/incipit) "Incipit | Definition of Incipit in English by Oxford Dictionaries." Oxford Dictionaries | English. Accessed March 22, 2018. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/incipit.

Comment: Thank you. I'd say it is close. However, "basmala" is just a shorter version. So it does not quite fit the definition of "colloquialism."

Comment: @blackened I've updated my answer, I think this answer is (very close to) what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is just about a shorter version of the full expression, then "shorthand" ([a short or quick way of showing or saying something](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shorthand)) might be appropriate.

Or "abbreviation" ([a shortened form of a written word or phrase used in place of the whole word or phrase](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abbreviation)).